# Jquery chat how track user session

Tags: php, jquery

We have implemented a JQuery chat in our company for internal communications. It is working fine. We are saving user status on data base, when a user logged in save his status on DB, when he logged out change status as log out.

Issue is that if any user does not click the logged out button and close the window or shut down his PC, he is still logged in our chat system.

How we can track if each user is logged in, possibly by tracking user session?

Comment: you should use a php function that it removes the db session of any user who has 15 mins of inactivity, so who ever is online will aromatically log them out, this way only one person would be logged in, and once that user tries to access the chat 16 mins after last activity, you trigger their login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way (but not safest or most robust) I would think to accomplish this would be via cookies.
First, the server/jquery script would put a cookie on the computer which is removed when the browser session ends when the user logs in. Then when they log out, remove the cookie. So when you want to check if the user is logged in, you look for the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that uses `CRON` for example:

Let user send to the server a small "pings" - messages that will tell server, that user is still logged in, active and have browser open. With every ping, update user's `last_activity` time to the current one.

With `CRON` you can check all users if their `last_activity` time is not bigger than 30 seconds for example. If so - set their status as logged off.

Simple SQL query for that:

```
UPDATE users
   SET logged_in = false
 WHERE logged_in = true
   AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - last_activity > 30
```